# How do you automatically confirm a modal in ruby using page-object?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, selenium-webdriver, page-object-gem

I have a standard rails application with a delete link. This delete link comes up with a browser popup modal (using rails `confirm` option).

I am currently attempting to test the delete function with Cucumber, Selenium-Webdriver (or Watir-Webdriver, still haven't decided), and the page-object gem.

Once the modal has been triggered, anything I do on the page gives me the following error:

```
Modal dialog present (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledAlertError)
```

I have been looking all over, but cannot find a way to handle this condition. If possible, I would like to continue using the `PageFactory` module in the page-object gem.

How can I dismiss/accept the modal?

Comment: Can you give an example of the modal dialog you are encountering? I believe the type impacts how you interact with it. For example a javascript alert and a jQueryUI modal dialog are both modal, but are interacted with differently (at least by Watir).

Comment: It is the standard Rails `link_to :confirm` modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this, but haven't decided upon the exact implementation.

In Javascript you can overwrite any function, which means you can overwrite the `confirm`

This means that you can run the following code to disable any popups.

```
def disable_popups
  # don't return anything for alert
  browser.execute_script("window.alert = function() {}")

  # return some string for prompt to simulate user entering it
  browser.execute_script("window.prompt = function() {return 'my name'}")

  # return null for prompt to simulate clicking Cancel
  browser.execute_script("window.prompt = function() {return null}")

  # return true for confirm to simulate clicking OK
  browser.execute_script("window.confirm = function() {return true}")

  # return false for confirm to simulate clicking Cancel
  browser.execute_script("window.confirm = function() {return false}")
end
```

If you put this inside the `initalize_page` function of a `page-object` then the dialogs are automatically removed.

```
def initialize_page
    disable_popups
end
```

Or you could do it right before the pop is triggered

```
def delete
  disable_popups
  delete_link # => clicks the link
end
```

References:

- [Testing Webpages with Javascript Popups Correctly](http://itreallymatters.net/post/1482786902/testing-webpages-with-javascript-popups-correctly#.UihszeZDulh)
- [Dismissing Pesky Javascript Dialogs with Watir](http://watirmelon.com/2010/10/31/dismissing-pesky-javascript-dialogs-with-watir/)

Answer (score 0):

The page object gem has methods to handle javascript popups - see the [original page-object gem post](http://www.cheezyworld.com/2011/07/29/introducing-page-object-gem/). In your case, I believe you want the [`confirm`](http://rubydoc.info/github/cheezy/page-object/master/PageObject#confirm-instance_method) method::

> (String) confirm(response, frame = nil, &block)
>
> Override the normal confirm popup so it does not occurr.
>
> Examples:
>
> message = @popup.confirm(true) do 
>        @page.button_that_causes_confirm 
>   end
>
> Parameters:
>
> - what (bool) — response you want to return back from the confirm popup
> - frame (defaults to: nil) — optional parameter used when the confirm is nested within a frame
> - block — a block that has the call that will cause the confirm to display
>
> Returns:
>
> (String) — the message that was prompted in the confirm

There is similar for the alert and prompt popups.

In your page-object, I would define:

```
class MyPage
  link(:delete_link, :id=>'delete')

  def delete()
    confirm(true){ delete_link }
  end
end
```

Then when you call page.delete, it will click the link and confirm the popup.